# How do I associate a name for UIView animation -animateWithDuration:

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, quartz-core

A name is associated with a CAAnimation:

```
[self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"name"];
```

How can I associate a name with animations initiated using UIView `-animateWithDuration:` ?
I would like to do this so I can cancel **this animation only**, hopefully by calling

```
[self.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: can't. To cancel UIView block based animation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967425/how-to-cancel-uiviews-block-based-animation?rq=1